# PHP Laravel Nova returns 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm working on a local `laravel-nova` project which worked fine the last couple of days. Now all of a sudden, when I try to go to the `/nova` route I get a `404` error saying `Page could not be found`. I tried with

```
php artisan config:cache
```

but without any luck. I even deleted the `vendor`-folder and ran `composer install` and `php artisan nova:install`, but that didn't solve it either.

When I run `php artisan route:list` I get the error:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\Laravel\Nova\Http\Controllers\LoginController does not exist

What happened? How can I solve this?

My Laravel version is 5.7 and I'm running this application on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Have you tried and `php artisan view:clear` ?

Comment: Or `php artisan cache:clear` to clear the whole cache

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa They both didn't solve it :-(

Comment: What about artisan config:clear

Comment: @cherrysoft Tried that - didn't work :s

Comment: OK, why the downvotes?

Comment: Did you register NovaServiceProvider?

Comment: @webmasterdro Yes I have, it was inside `config/app.php` after the installation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add on **app/config/app.php**

```
App\Providers\NovaServiceProvider::class,
```

inside  'providers'.

You may need to run these commands later if that doesn't work:

```
php artisan nova:publish
```

And

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: Yes - `php artisan nova:publish` was actually the thing that solved it! Forgot to mention it :-) Thanks anyway - I will accept your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I found it out myself, so just in case other users may have the same problem I'm going to post an answer.

So, if you may have a route like for example:

```
Route::get('{subpage}', 'SubpagesController@show');
```

This will return the `404` and you will not be able to access Nova, e.g., the dashboard since Nova (from version 1.0.9) is always registering its routes after the application's routes.

You will have to change the `config/nova.php` path to either `no/va` or simply `nova` by removing the `/`.

See [here](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/445) for more.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try following commands in your terminal:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, add the following code in your virtual host:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/checkin>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

In file *LoginController*, add `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`.

Comment: In which one? `App\Http\Controllers\LoginController` or `vendor\laravel\nova\src\Http\Controllers\LoginController` ?

Comment: Send vendor\laravel\nova\src\Http\Controllers\ directory list

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the `App\Providers\NovaServiceProvider` was added to the `providers` array in your `app\config.php` configuration file. If it wasn't, you should add it manually. Of course, if your application does not use the App namespace, you should update the provider class name as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laragon.

In my case, in file *config/app.php*, add

```
App\Providers\NovaServiceProvider::class,
```

I then tried

```
php artisan nova:publish
```

But still a 404 error was coming, and then the following

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the nova routes are listed using the below:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: Re *"Try checking the nova routes are listed using the below:"*: This is partly incomprehensible. Are you using [machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate)? Can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I battled this for a long time when I was setting up a new laptop and since it was a different answer for me I thought I would share it in case it helps anyone else.

My problem was that I copied the .env file from another computer after cloning the repo.

I spent hours battling this before I discovered that the `NOVA_DOMAIN_NAME` environmental variable is critical here.

Be sure that variable matches the domain name you are using on the computer that is giving you the 404. I needed the `.local` TLD and it fixed it, but you will need to use your own of course.